# How to change the style of a source reference in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have a number of references in Word 2007; there is several way of referencing them and the one I find the most fitting is purely numeric, e.g. (3) for reference number 3 in the list. But since I reference equations by round parenthesis, I'd like to change the literature references to square brackets.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is this similar to http://superuser.com/questions/144253/how-to-put-square-brakcets-for-bibliographic-references-in-microsoft-word ?

Comment: @AdamV - yes, I believe so. I saw that one in my quick search. Unfortunatelly, I've found no way of contacting the author of both the question and the answer.

Comment: While this is a duplicate of that question, the answer to it is not very helpful.  At any rate, this question could likely produce a better answer than the one already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add / change the referencing styles in Word 2007 by the addition / modification of some XSLT (XML Stylesheet) files. *By default* these files can be found in:
**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\1033\Bibliography\Style**.

I'm afriad I have no direct personal experience of editing these files, only installing a pre-build additional style (which is simply achieved by placing the new `.xsl` in to the folder quoted about).

Cloning the style you are currently using and tweaking it might give you a starting point, but you might want to look at the following first:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100821095626/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/microsoft_office_word/archive/2007/12/14/bibliography-citations-1011.aspx?)

Comment: I'll try to follow those instructions then. Best advice yet ;-) Thank you.