# How do I set MLA citation style to use numeric reference in MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, citations

The MLA citation style shows citations as (Author, YYYY) or some similar while I'd prefer it to style them numerically, like [1]. I have tried BibWord, I don't know XML.

- [Creating references that are bracketed numbers, not citation](https://superuser.com/questions/625333/creating-references-that-are-bracketed-numbers-not-citation) — not what I need, I really don't see an existing style (not even in the BibWord collection) which would do what I'm after.
- [Improved APA citation format in Word 2007/2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/232116/improved-apa-citation-format-in-word-2007-2010) - related, but I don't think I can fiddle with BibWord Extender, it's a commandline tool.
- [How to change the style of a source reference in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/152290/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-source-reference-in-word) — OK, helpful, but I really wouldn't like to edit XML manually. The URL provided also is 404.

Please provide me with means of solving such task.

---

BibWord has a list of styles none of which match the requirement. It also has a tool which does not appear to do what I am after.

---

No, I'm not looking for ISO 690. The style requirement only has a few examples, like the one below.

[1]     Guo, Z.Y., Zhu, H.Y., Liang, X.G., “Entransy - A physical quantity describing heat transfer ability,” *Int. J. Heat Mass Transf.*, 50(13-14), pp. 2545-2556, (2007).

Comment: MLA does not use numbered citations, ever.  You are looking for ISO 960 Citations.

Comment: did Bibword not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Bibword is quite simple to use and the citations that you need are the **iso960 square bracket citations** [found here](http://bibword.codeplex.com/releases/view/14646).

Download the .XSL (not a typo) file and copy it into the Microsoft Word bibliography style directory. This directory can vary depending on where Word is installed:

On most 32-bits machines with Microsoft Word 2010 this will be:

```
%programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\Bibliography\Style
```

Put that code into a RUN box and copy the XSL file into there.

(if that doesn't work, search your hard drive for `winword.exe` and open the `Bibliography` folder and then the `Style` folder found there.)

Once the styles are copied to the directory, they will show up every time Microsoft Word is opened.